# cannot receive the right data of NONIN OEM III using PIC32

Tags: pic, sensor, programming, microchip, mplabx

I am looking for a solution for my project. I am using PIC32MX270F256B from Microchip,nonin oem III module and UART. I have connected the serial out pin from nonin (pin number 12), to U2RX pin of PIC (pin number 22) [image: schematic diagram of the board]
This circuit consists of accelerometer, nonin oem sensor, and temperature sensor. Only the nonin oem sensor did not function well. I use red led as a confirmation LED for U2RX receiver interrupt in programming, but the led does not light up which means the U2RX interrupt does not functioned well.

When I checked the data transmission at the terminal, 3 bytes of data [status, Heart Rate(HR), SPO2] were sent but in state of 00, 00, 00, which means the sensor could not read user's heart rate and SPO2 at all.

I have made the same circuit but using a different communication unit and different PIC before ( bluetooth instead of Xbee, and dsPIC33 instead of PIC32) and it works well. Thus, i do not think that there is any problem with the nonin oem sensor.

Could anyone recheck my schematic diagram? (i want to post other pictures like the real board diagram, the result that are shown at the terminal and some programming part here but I am allowed to post only one link) Those who wants to help and in need of more details/pictures/links, do drop your emails here and I will contact you privately later.

Comment: Were is the link? As external sites can be unreliable, it is always best to put related content directly here.

Comment: sorry my bad. its not a link. its just the schematic diagram picture.

Answer (score 1):

My first observation, you seem to be missing decoupling capacitors. Which could cause some issues. Second observation, your pin numbering on the oem module is incorrect so ether you have it wired wrong or you assembled something different that the schematic you showed here.